# Program type already present: org.codehaus.jackson

Tags: java, android, gradle, jackson

As of today I suddenly got an error in an old project I di not open in a while, but used to work.

*Error: Program type already present: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser$1*

It happens with all kinds of org.codehaus.jackson modules randomly.

I think its because of including projects that use the jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar and referencing maven repository, so I tried excluding it with every variation of exclude group: and exclude module: and the path but no luck.

build.gradle from main project

[image]

build.gradle from included project

[image]

I even had a look into the gradle app:dependencies and I see them there but I just can't get it excluded. Deleting it from the Projects does not work as it is needed there.

```
    Executing tasks: [androidDependencies]

:syncFramework:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

debugAndroidTest
debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

debugUnitTest
debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

release
releaseCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

releaseRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

releaseUnitTest
releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar

releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
\--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
:syncFrameworkPlain:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

debugAndroidTest
debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

debugUnitTest
debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

release
releaseCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

releaseRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

releaseUnitTest
releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar

releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
\--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
:wundoffice:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: debug)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: debug)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar

debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: debug)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: debug)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar

debugAndroidTest
debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: debug)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: debug)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar

debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging

debugUnitTest
debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: debug)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: debug)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar

debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: debug)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: debug)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar

release
releaseCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: release)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: release)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar

releaseRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: release)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: release)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar

releaseUnitTest
releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: release)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: release)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar

releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\itextg-5.5.1.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\licensekey-1.0.2.jar
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\wundoffice\libs\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
+--- :syncFramework (variant: release)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFramework\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- :syncFrameworkPlain (variant: release)
+--- D:\Android-Studio-Workspace\Wundoffice\syncFrameworkPlain\libs\jackson-mini-1.9.6.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89@aar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2@jar
+--- net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-j2se:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-base:3.6.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kxml:kxml:2.2.4@jar
+--- net.sourceforge.kobjects:kobjects-j2me:0.0-SNAPSHOT-20040926-2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0@jar
+--- org.xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.3@jar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0@jar
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from the so, so old org.codehaus librarys to the newest and changing all the imports to com.fasterxml solved the conflict